# grub in centOS, I can't start my Server

Tags: centos, rhel, grub, startup

I was changing my HD with a (Windows Program for Partitions), now I can't start the server, CentOS.

[image]

I remember this:

```
/etc/grub.conf &
default=1
timeout=10
splashimage=(hd0,4)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
#hiddenmenu
```

**How can I recover the system?**

**Can I to map the HD?**

Here using **Disk Utility** of DVDLive

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| System Reserved |    Windows    |         Extended  W95 Ext d(LBA)(0x0f)          |
|      NTFS       |      NTFS     |                  /dev/sdb3                      |
|    Bootable     |               |-------------------------------------------------|
|   /dev/sdb1     |   /dev/sdb2   |     (fat32)  |  Linux (0x83) | Linux LVM (0x8e) |
|                 |               |   /dev/sdb4  |   /dev/sdb5   |   /dev/sdb6      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I get access to `grub.conf` with:

```
$ su
# mkdir /mnt/drv
# mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb5 /mnt/drv
# gedit /mnt/drv/grub/grub.conf
```

using `parted` (The *Start*, *End* and *Size* are no exact)

```
# parted /dev/sdb

Number Start   End       Size     Type     File system    Flags
 1     1049kB  106MB     105MB    primary   ntfs          boot  
 2     xxxMB   yy.yGB    zz.zGB   primary   ntfs            
 3     xxxMB   yy.yGB    zz.zGB   extended
 4     xxxMB   yy.yGB    zz.zGB   logical   fat32
 5     xxxMB   yy.yGB    zz.zGB   logical   ext4
 6     xxxMB   yy.yGB    zz.zGB   logical                 lvm
```

The logical lvm

Now, I'm confused to edit `grub.conf` file.
And I'm suspecting that some partition (3, 4, 5, 6) must be Primary, but I don't know what it should be.

Comment: In the future please post your screen as text.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the grub boot loader IS installed on the HD, BUT grub cannot find the grub.cfg file, or there is an error in the file.

The easiest way to replace the grub.cfg file would be to boot from an CD or USB with [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/). This will allow you to boot into the server OS where you are most comfortable and run the `grub-mkconfig` command to replace your grub.cfg file.

You could use almost any 'live' linux OS to boot into to do the same but be mindful of the server OS location and use the correct switches in `grub-mkconfig`.

Looks like a good inclusive How To [here.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-GRUB2-features/)

Comment: trying with: `grub-mkconfig` but it was not recognized!.
Later: I burn a LiveDVD 6.8, and I gain access to `/grub/grub.conf`, but I'm changing this file and the results are equals...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you...

I solved my problem

Using `LiveDVD` of *CentOS-6.8-i386*, I Opened **Disk Utility**

Reviewing the Hard Disk Distribution... I see the Partition **sdb4** maybe is not correct for Linux, and maybe is "hidden (is front of **sdb5** Swap Partition) the corrects **sdb5** and **sdb6**"...

I deleted the **sdb4** (fat32) partition, 
Restored the initial Settings of `grub.conf` with:

```
$ su
# mkdir /mnt/drv
# mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb5 /mnt/drv
# gedit /mnt/drv/grub/grub.conf
```